# Cygwin compiling HPLIP on windows xp

Tags: build, cygwin

Cygwin compiling HPLIP on windows xp:
Could build cups-1.6b1 , net-snmp-5.7.2 and sane 1.0.23 successfully on windows xp machine with cygwin.But not able to build hplip-3.13.4

Getting following error on ./configure
configure: error: cannot find libcups support

Stuck here.I will greatly appreciate any help.
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

According to [that](http://dreamlayers.blogspot.ru/2010/01/compiling-hplip-in-windows-using-cygwin.html) post, where HPLIP is also being built under Cygwin, you should use these flags, as I suppose:

```
--with-cupsbackenddir=/opt/hplip/lib/cups/backend 
--with-cupsfilterdir=/opt/hplip/lib/cups/filter
```